# .NET Core Web Application - app_offline equivalent / Safely stop web application for maintenance

Tags: apache, web-applications, centos, .net-core, offline

If hosting a web application with IIS I know there's an app_offline.htm file that can be used, but I'm hosting a .NET core web app in a Linux environment with apache. Anyone know what the safest approach is to taking an app offline in this situation so that I can make changes to my app without breaking anything?

EDIT: The intent is to keep the website online, but prevent login or any interactions within a web application until maintenance tasks are complete and app restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research, I made something that should serve the purposes of an 'app_offline' by using an ActionFilter.

Using dependency injection, this filter takes a boolean value set in my appsettings.json and if set to true it's read into the action filter and redirects users to a 'down for maintenance' page. It is my understanding that using IOptionsSnapshot instead of IOptions will get the value if changed during runtime. This is also nice when you have a public facing website but only want the backend application to prevent any actions until changes have been made and the app restarted. Below is an example of my ActionFilter. Only thing I don't like is that this filter has to be set on pretty much every controller in the app. I'd prefer coming up with something that could be checked sooner in the pipeline, so if anyone has a better approach I'd love to see it.

```
private readonly ServiceSettings _settings;

public AppStateAttribute(IOptionsSnapshot<ServiceSettings> options)
{
    _settings = options.Value;
}

public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if(_settings.AppOffline)
    {
        var redirectOnFail = "/maintenance";

        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectOnFail, true);
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```